# geometrical Intuition that integral around a closed coutour of 1/z^3 is zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I need geometrical interpretation that the integral is zero, i have found for 1/z^2 but could not find for cubic powers of z in denominator. For integral of 1/z^2, i write it as 1/((z-epsilon)(z+epsilon)) and make spsilon as small as possivle then by distorting the contour, both the sense of the integrals are opposite so it becomes zero but for cubic function, the answer becomes indeterminate, what am i missing

Comment: You could do the same, but instead of using $\varepsilon$ and $-\varepsilon$, use $\zeta_3^k\varepsilon$, where $\zeta_3$ is a primitive cubic root of unity ($\mathrm e^{\frac{2\pi\mathrm i}{3}}$ for instance) and $k\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: Please can show it @vercassivelaunos

Comment: $\frac{1}{z^3}\approx\frac{1}{(z-\varepsilon)(z-\varepsilon e^{2\pi\mathrm i/3})(z-\varepsilon e^{4\pi\mathrm i/3})}$. Now you can also distort contours around these poles such that the poles cancel each other out.